# homebrew mysql unknown option '--skip-bdb'

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I've just installed a fresh installation of mysql via homebrew and when I do a `'mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami`--basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp'` I get the following error:

```
>Installing MySQL system tables...
>
>111215 19:03:41 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
>
>111215 19:03:41 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
>
>111215 19:03:41 [ERROR] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.15/bin/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-bdb'
>
>111215 19:03:41 [ERROR] Aborting
>
>111215 19:03:41 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.15/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
>
>Installation of system tables failed!
```

Does anyone know why I might be getting this error I've tried google around but can't find anything specially on `"unknown option '--skip-bdb'"`

Comment: The `--skip-bdb` option is in the `mysql_install_db` file for my `Windows MySQL 5.5.24` installation, right after a `@FIXME` comment. A lot of other issues pops in when you remove that line (like `Unknown InnoDB engine`) so I took the `data` directory from MySQL 5.5 download instead of trying to re-create it with the perl script.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the script `mysql_install_db` is loading the default my.cnf (check /etc/my.cnf) file from another installation, in the version 5.1 [--skip-dbd was removed](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50336).

You must remove this file or this option from this config file.